# O-auth flow explanation in the case below?

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth

From what i understand about the login process in oauth apps is that the client first gets redirected to oauth server and then back to webapp. Recently i noticed the authentication flow on [freelancer.com](https://www.freelancer.com) specifically in there facebook login. There was no redirection to facebook servers. On clicking all i got is this page [image]. How exactly are they doing this. I know that it is `oauth` because i initially granted the apps permissions but what is the authorization flow after that ?

### Edit

Just to check if it was actually making the request i logged out of fb and tried again and i got

[image]

Comment: _“the client first gets redirected to oauth server and then back to webapp”_ – with the server-side login flow, yes. But the client-side flow using the JS SDK does not need to redirect, but makes requests in the background. And it can recognize users that have already logged in to the app before, when they return to the site.

Comment: @CBroe now i get it what i was missing. Add an answer and i'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the client first gets redirected to oauth server and then back to webapp

With the [server-side login flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow), yes.

But the client-side flow using the [JS SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript) does not need to redirect, but makes requests in the background. And it can recognize users that have already logged in to the app before, when they return to the site.

Comment: thanks a lot this was really bugging on on implementation side :)